# Azure CLI. Is it possible to update/set default documents for web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have a web app on azure and i want to add a value `app_offline.htm` in Default Documents through `azure cli 2.0`:
[image]

I looked at [`az webapp config appsettings set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-appsettings-set), but this sets the config and not the default document.

Did someone encounter this?
Is there a solution to doing this through CLI and not manually through Azure UI?

Comment: Have a look at the CLI Reference on the [Azure Websites Cheat Sheet](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#cross-platform). Looks like something like `azure site defaultdocument add app_offline.htm`

Comment: Have you try my command?

Comment: @JoyWang sorry, currently doing something else, but I will check.

Comment: @JoyWang sorry to keep you waiting, you solution exactly what i wanted! thanks!

Comment: @JoyWang done! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

You could try the command below, replace the `<yourresourcegroup>` and `<yourwebappname>`, it works fine on my side.

```
az resource update --resource-group <yourresourcegroup> --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" --name <yourwebappname>/config/web --add properties.defaultDocuments app_offline.htm
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, yes, this is a viable option, as well...just not the best experience. :)

Comment: @twitchax Yes, but actually it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Changing that setting is not currently possible in Azure CLI 2.0, but it would be great if you could file an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) (better when it comes from customers).

However, you can use [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview) to achieve this today.

```
$webapp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName rg -Name name
$webapp.SiteConfig.DefaultDocuments.Add("new.html")
Set-AzureRmWebApp $webapp
```